# Is it possible to return a condition from CASE as a string?

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I want to do the following:

```
SELECT order 
FROM ORDERS  
WHERE order <> 0   
  AND (CASE
           WHEN orders.productcount IS NOT NULL 
               THEN orders.productcount = 1  
               ELSE orders.productcount IS NOT NULL 
       END)
```

Is something like this possible? I've tried with '', with "", without, but there is always something missing. This will be used in a 3rd party app, but I need to first see if it is possible in standard SQL.

EDIT: Logic in the example might not be entirely correct, because it is not the real query.

EDIT 2:I am using a variable that is based on userinput. 1 and 0. The idea is to show records without invoice if its 1 and show all if 0.

> --@@ :var_InvCheck = AND (CASE WHEN :var_InvCheck=1 THEN invoice.number IS NOT NULL ELSE invoice.number IS NULL AND invoice.number IS NOT NULL END)

EDIT 3: This is the end result:
[image]

I want to let user decide if he wants to see records with missing invoice number or only those that have invoice number.

**EDIT 4:**
After a couple of corrections and comments I made a dummy DB to demonstrate what I want. Here is the code:

> CREATE TABLE products (PK_productID int, name Varchar(32), totalamount int);

> CREATE TABLE orders (PK_orderID int, FK_productID int, FK_customerID int,   quantity int);

> INSERT INTO products (PK_productID, name,  totalamount) VALUES(1, 'product1', 500);
> INSERT INTO products (PK_productID, name,  totalamount) VALUES(2, 'product2', 250);
> INSERT INTO products (PK_productID, name,  totalamount) VALUES(3, 'product3', 100);
>
> INSERT INTO orders (PK_orderID, FK_productID, FK_customerID, quantity) VALUES(1, 1, 1390, 10);
> INSERT INTO orders (PK_orderID, FK_productID, FK_customerID, quantity) VALUES(2, 1, 1390, 10);
> INSERT INTO orders (PK_orderID, FK_productID, FK_customerID, quantity) VALUES(3, 2, 1390, null);

> SELECT PK_orderID FROM orders WHERE PK_orderID >0 AND (CASE WHEN
> quantity IS NOT NULL THEN quantity=1 ELSE quantity IS NOT NULL END)

What I want to achieve is the following: At the end in the `WHERE` clause after `AND` I want to have a different condition based on whether the condition in the `CASE` is met. In the example if `quantity` is not empty, I want to see all records that have `quantity=1`, if `quantity is NULL` then I want to see all records that are **not** `quantity = NULL`.

Comment: Could you please show sample input and expected outcome as tables?

Comment: You need to be more specific.  "something missing" does not help. I don't see any string in your query, kust a number.  We don't know the field definitions in ORDERS table.

Comment: Oracle have no Boolean datatype, this should be expressed as conditions

Comment: I edited the question to be a bit more specific.

Comment: It's not more specific. Why don't you show sample input and expected result?

Comment: Because I can't show the data or tables. This is why I am changing it. This is the most i can share. Added EDIT 3.

Comment: Perhaps you could show dummy data and tables that illustrate the technical issue without sharing confidential details.

Comment: Added Edit4 with a dummy DB. This should unlock the thread.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your revised description:

```
WHERE ... AND (
    :var_InvCheck = 1 AND invoice.number IS NOT NULL OR
    :var_InvCheck = 0
)
```

PS: I would rather use two separate queries (different where clause) based on user input instead of one "catch all" query.

Answer (score 0):

I read it as

```
where order <> 0        
  and prodcount = case when productcount is not null then 1 
                       else productcount 
                  end
```